# Python Hazelcast Client timeout

Tags: kubernetes, hazelcast

I'm using the open-source 5.0 Hazelcast cluster which was deployed on k8s. However, I have been met connection issues from client to server with smart client strategy.

I used python code example as above:

```
client = HazelcastClient(
cluster_name="dev",
ssl_password="password",
cluster_members=[
  "IPADDRESS1_MASTER_K8s:Nodeport1"
  "IPADDRESS2_MASTER_K8s:Nodeport2"
  "IPADDRESS3_MASTER_K8s:Nodeport3"
],
)
```

Issue:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsKpr.png)

Thanks all.

Comment: Btw, after each cluster member there should be a ','

Answer (score 1):

You should enable External Smart Client Discovery by passing `use_public_ip=True` to the client constructor:

```
client  = HazelcastClient(
...
use_public_ip=True
...
)
```

That should solve the issue.

Comment: I also feel like the problem is this. If your client is external to the k8s cluster, see the following guide for more information about the cluster and client setup for smart client https://guides.hazelcast.org/kubernetes-external-client/

Comment: I used NodePort service and followed the guide but it's not working. Did you use to enterprise or opensource Hazelcast version?